# Ruby on Rails - Partial not rendering link on creation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Yo guys, I'm learning Rails and having a interesing problem

I have a this partial.

**_access_point.html.erb**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="card-title">
      <h3 class="text-center"><%= link_to_unless_current access_point.model.upcase, [access_point] %><%= link_to [:edit, access_point], remote: true, class: 'float-right' do fa_icon 'edit lg' end %></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-text">
      <p><strong>Manufacturer: </strong><%= access_point.manufacturer %></p>
      <p><strong>Serial number: </strong><%= access_point.serial_number %></p>
      <p><strong>USER: </strong><%= access_point.user %></p>
      <p><strong>PASSWORD: </strong><%= access_point.password %></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$('#access-points-cards').append('<%= j render partial: 'access_point', locals: { access_point: @access_point }, layout: 'layouts/col-md-4' %>')
$('#new-access-point').modal('hide')
```

and I´m using a modal form, with remote: true to create it, after inserting the EDIT button don´t show up in the browser, but show in the dev tools, if I hit F5 it shows everything ok, don´t know if its a turbolinks problem or something like that.

Can you help me?

Comment: So the `_access_point` partial isn't rendered at all or there are some problems with it after it got rendered?

Comment: it is rendered normally. `<h3 class="text-center"><%= link_to_unless_current access_point.model.upcase, [access_point] %><%= link_to [:edit, access_point], remote: true, class: 'float-right' do fa_icon 'edit lg' end %></h3>` in this part of the partial, the link_to_unless_current works normally, but the fa_icon doesn´t show

Answer (score 1):

Your problem should be the view is not being updated in the DOM properly.
So instead of appending try this:

- Render your `access_point` view on your page always
- Change your partial to be hidden with:

  **access_point.html.erb** :
  `<div class="card hidden">`

  **some_css_file** : 
  `hidden { display: none }`
- Show partial on js call
  **create.js.erb**

  `$('.card').show()
  $('#new-access-point').modal('hide')`
- Decide where to place `$('.card').hide()` if needed